# Ubuntu runned on my usb stick meets often segmentation faults

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I've installed ubuntu on my usb stick `Sandisk Extreme` http://www.sandisk.com/products/usb/drives/extreme/ , which is hardcorely efficient.

But I met a trouble. In the random moments of the time `segmentation faults` are happened and processes shut down. What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

> In the random moments of the time segmentation faults are happened and processes shut down. What can I do to avoid that?

Indeed, this is also my experience when trying to run standard Ubuntu off of a USB flash drive. Some drives can take it, others can't, presumably due to firmware bugs. Try with a less-hardcorely-efficient drive.

Comment: I need to make my ubuntu drive transportable. What can you say about HDD with usb connector? Would it be stable like a usual HDD through sata connector?

Comment: @asiniy I've never had problems with those.